# List of checkboxes in select html tag with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to acheive [this](http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/hlmri) using Angular. I want to use it in a form so that I can retreive my checked values as an array in my controller. I know that I can create custom directives in order to create a custom form control using `ngModel`. But I think I don't need to create a custom directive for a control like that.

I saw that they are a lot of code that can do this using jQuery but I'm using Angular.

Can anyone give me the best way to acheive this? (HTML, Custom Directive, ...)

Thank you

Comment: http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/

Comment: This is extactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much !